# Tyepscript Array.map returns array of JSX.Element instead of custom component type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
var items = values.map((x, index) =>
   <CustomComponent key={index} />);
```

This returns `JSX.Element[]`. Why doesn't it return `typeof CustomComponent[]`?

With the former, then I can't use `items.sort` without difficult errors.

Comment: I would sort the `values` before mapping to an element. Think of that as the last step before displaying ui.

Comment: It  returns JSX element type `Element[]`, which would contain `<CustomComponent/> as array items

Comment: What is inside your `<CustomComponent/>`?

Comment: JSX in react is really just sugar for calls to React.createElement, which in turn returns a - you guessed it - JSX.Element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct. It returns `JSX.Element[]` because you are rendering `CustomComponent` immediately.
If you want to work with element sort/filter or something else you need filter data before render.

```
values
   .filter(x => //filter your values)
   .map((x, index) => // render your components
<CustomComponent key={index} />);
```

Answer (score 0):

yes,

like Egor said, your map result is CustomComponent resuls array.

if you want to your component instance array try some thing like this

```
export  type CustomComponentType = () => JSX.Element;

export  const CustomComponent : CustomComponentType = ()=> {
    return <div>my componen result</div>
} 

export const test : CustomComponentType[] = ()=> {
    const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    const componentArray =  array.map(c => CustomComponent);
    return componentArray;
}
```